# Persistent Indexing for Files and Folders in Network Drive WIndows Explorer Properties

Tags: windows, networking, search-indexing, smbclient, smb2

I can acces my SSD via my NAS via SMB just fine.
Windows properties pane shows a checkbox near Indexed files/folders.

No matter how many times I disable Indexing for this particular network drive, after clicking apply and after all files have been Un-indexed, I reopened the properties box.

The checkbox near Indexing has reappeared.

Some of my local drives have Indexing Unchecked, and remain unindexed (the checkbox there stays unchecked).

On this drive however the checkbox re-appears every time.
After numerous restarts and trails and searched invail, I'm asking here.

What is the culprit here?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use Control Panel, Indexing Options, and remove the NAS from the Indexing Locations.

Look on the screen shot, left side and make NAS folders have not been selected.

When you remove the NAS, you may wish to reindex and let it run overnight. Then check

[image]

Comment: Thanks John for your suggestions and printscreens!
I did not knew this, I unchecked Everything except Microsoft Outlook.
The checkbox in properties was still checked in Explorer. I unchecked it. Applied. Reopened the properties pane and there was the pesky checkbox again. So this did not help my situation with the persistent pesky Indexing option.

Comment: Something wrong with your properties I think. Indexing Options have worked well for me from XP through to Windows 11.  Should work here.  Maybe try running DISM / SFC to correct.  (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

Comment: How do you even index a network drive.  I *want* my network drive to be indexed because it's really a WSL mounted ext4 drive, but i'm tearing my hair out because I can't figure out *how*

Comment: You cannot (in the vast majority of cases) index a network  of cases because the network drive can be disconnected, screwing up the index.

Comment: Remember that a Network drive is different than a permanently connected NAS in this respect

Answer (score 0):

I reached out to Microsoft about this maybe 17 years ago.  It makes no sense for every workstation in an organization to index a shared drive when there are tens of thousands of workstations. I showed them how it always reenables itself as well.  The discussion never went anywhere.  I suppose they assume a company must disable indexing nw shares if they want end user workstations not to index their mapped drives but that seems like a poor default function.  To me, by default, this means every workstation, file server, and the overall network must be bogged down with indexing for that feature to keep performing its duty.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1214252)

Comment: except.. what if a shared drive isn't really shared... there are valid local mounts that appear as shared drives even though they really aren't